# How to redirect user to welcome page by authenticating its enterd details in login form with db in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have created a model for signup form and allowed user to enter its data ,which is further stored in DB , then I have created a login form which take the detail of user like email and password and then verifies it in db and allows user to redirect to welcome page
I am attaching my code details

INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>What do u want/?</h1>
    <button class="submit"><a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a></button>
    <button class="submit"><a href="{% url 'signup' %}">signup</a></button>
</body>
</html>
```

LOGIN.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">     
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="password">
        <button class="submit">submit</button>
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

SIGNUP.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" >  
        {% csrf_token %}      
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="name"><br>       
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="email"><br>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="password">
        <button class="submit"><a href="{% url 'welcome' %}">submit</a></button>
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

WELCOME.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome {{name}}</h1>
    
</body>
</html>
```

VIEWS.PY

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import Detailsform
from home.models import Details
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,logout,login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')
def login(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        email=request.POST['email']
        password=request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            # Login was successful, log the user in
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page or perform any desired actions
            return redirect('welcome')  # Replace 'welcome' with your desired login success page
        else:
            # Authentication failed, display an error message
            return redirect('signup')
       
    return render(request,'login.html')
def signup(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
         name=request.POST.get('name')
         email=request.POST.get('email')
         password=request.POST.get('password')
         data=Details(name=name,email=email,password=password)
         data.save()            
    else:
        form=Detailsform()        
    return render(request,'signup.html')        

def welcome(request):
    name=Details.objects.last();
    return render(request,'welcome.html',{'name':name})
```

MODELS.PY

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Details(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=50)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

FORMS.PY

```
from django import forms
from .models import Details

class Detailsform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Details
        fields = ['name', 'email','password']
```

I am not able to login user with the same details in db .I am still in the learning phase of django kindly help me.